# Culling post data from wp-load returns garbled characters

Tags: php, wordpress

I have just installed WordPress on a subdirectory, now I want to cull 3 recent WordPress posts and display it on a custom PHP page but I get garbled characters instead of the posts data and it also breaks my webpage. Below are the line of codes responsible for culling the WordPress posts.

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
            <?php
                include ('blog/wp-load.php');
                $args = array(
                // 'cat' => 3, // Only source posts from a specific category
                'posts_per_page' => 3 // Specify how many posts you'd like to display
                );
                $latest_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
                if ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
                $latest_posts->the_post();
            ?>
            <div class="col-xl-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="single-blog-inner">
                    <div class="thumb">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrap-details">
                        <h6><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h6>
                        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                        <a class="read-more-btn" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
                        <span class="date float-end"><?php the_time('l jS F, Y') ?></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php }
                } else {
                echo '<p>There are no posts available</p>';
                }
                wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>
    </div>
```

I have my webpage encoded with "UTF-8" and my WordPress blog is running version 5.7.2 with debug set to true.

I have ran out of ideas on what could be the issue and will greatly appreciate any help or pointer!

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was, I should have used

"include ('blog/wp-blog-header.php');"

instead of

"include ('blog/wp-load.php');"

The latter had been working for me in earlier versions of WordPress but it seems this most recent version does not support it.